# radio button list and radio button asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

My code is as follows.Here I have a problem, that I just want one to be selected either rdbtn5 or any one radio list item.But it is able to select both. Please suggest.

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="70%" style="padding-left:10px; text-decoration-color:white">
                <div class="content" style="display: inline-block !important;">
                     <asp:RadioButton ForeColor="White" ID="rdContribute" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdContribute_CheckedChanged"  Text="abc"<br/>  GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" /><!--onchange="Monthly()" -->

                    <div style="display:block;margin-left:10px;" id="dvrdList">
                     <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rdlist" ForeColor="White" GroupName="Selected1" runat="server">                            
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Rs.100/month(Rs.1200/Year)" Value="100" name="abc" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>                              
                          <asp:ListItem Text="R.250/month(Rs.3000/Year)" Value="250" name="abc"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Rs.500/month(Rs.6000/Year)" Value="500" name="abc"></asp:ListItem>    
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Rs.1000/month(Rs.12000/Year)" Value="1000" name="abc"></asp:ListItem>  
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Rs.5000/month(Rs.60000/Year)" Value="5000" name="abc"></asp:ListItem> 

                       </asp:RadioButtonList>

                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdbtn5" name="abc" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdContribute_CheckedChanged" GroupName="Selected1"/><asp:TextBox ID="tbGreater" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" CausesValidation="true" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                       <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1000" MaximumValue="1000000" ControlToValidate="tbGreater" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter digits greater than 1000"></asp:RangeValidator>

                     </div>
                    <asp:RadioButton ForeColor="White" ID="rdNo" AutoPostBack="true" Text="I do not wish to make a contribution" OnCheckedChanged="rdNo_CheckedChanged" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />           

                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:RadioButton ForeColor="White" ID="rdReminder" AutoPostBack="true" name="rdReminder" Visible="false" OnCheckedChanged="rdReminder_CheckedChanged" Text="def" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />
            </td>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the RadioButtonList `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

```
    protected void rdlist_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //uncheck all checkboxes
        rdbtn1.Checked = false;
        rdbtn2.Checked = false;
        rdbtn3.Checked = false;
        rdbtn4.Checked = false;
        rdbtn5.Checked = false;
    }
```

Add this event to all other RadioButtons

```
    protected void globalRadio_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //uncheck all checkboxes
        rdbtn1.Checked = false;
        rdbtn2.Checked = false;
        rdbtn3.Checked = false;
        rdbtn4.Checked = false;
        rdbtn5.Checked = false;

        //uncheck all checkboxes in the list
        foreach (ListItem listItem in rdlist.Items)
        {
            listItem.Selected = false;
        }

        //re-check the clicked radiobutton
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        rb.Checked = true;
    }
```

Comment: This works only once. After selecting rdbtn5, If I click on any other Rdlist Item, the same problem occurs

Comment: Updated my answer. You may need to tweak it a little to get it to work in your situation.